# How can I check the reverse relations?

Tags: python, django

My models:

```py
class OrderItem(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    pack = models.ForeignKey(Pack, on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=True, null=True)


class Pack(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(max_length=100, blank=True)
```

How can I check the reverse relations? I want to get all Pack-s that are not in OrderItem-s (in pack field).

I solve it like this, but I think it`s a terrible way:

```py
orderItems = OrderItem.objects.all()
packItems = Pack.objects.all()

for packItem in packItems:
    for orderItem in orderItems:
        if orderItem.pack == packItem:
            print('Yeah, you found one of them')
```

PS Terrible, because "Pack" have more than 5k lines

Answer (score 0):

you should do something like this.

```
pack = Pack.objects.first()
order_items = pack.orderitem_set.all()
```

orderitem_set is the default name that django will assign for reverse relation you can reassign this name by adding related_name attribute in OrderItem.pack to look like this

```
class OrderItem(models.Model):
      name = models.TextField(max_length=100, blank=True)
      pack = models.ForeignKey(Pack, on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=True, null=True, 
                       related_name="anything_i_want")
```

Answer (score 0):

To get all the `Pack` objects that are not referenced by `OrderItem` objects, you can do it in a single query using the (somewhat strange) syntax:

```py
Pack.objects.filter(orderitem__isnull=True)
```

This uses the reverse relationship `orderitem` (from the default `orderitem_set`). If you want to change `orderitem` and `orderitem_set`, you can use:

```py
class OrderItem(models.Model):
    pack = models.ForeignKey(Pack, on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=True, null=True, related_name="order_items") # or whatever you want to call it
```

Then just replace `orderitem` (and `orderitem_set`) with the value of `related_name`.